# grep for words ending in 'ing' immediately after a comma

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to grep files for lines with a word ending in 'ing' immediately after a comma, of the form:

```
... we gave the dog a bone, showing great generosity ...
... this man, having no home ...
```

but not:

```
... this is a great place, we are having a good time ...
```

I would like to find instances where the 'ing' word is *the first word* after a comma.  It seems like this should be very doable in grep, but I haven't figured out how, or found a similar example.

I have tried

```
grep -e ", .*ing"
```

which matches multiple words after the comma.  Commands like

```
grep -i -e ", [a-z]{1,}ing"
grep -i -e ", [a-z][a-z]+ing"
```

don't do what I expect--they don't match phrases like my first two examples.  Any help with this (or pointers to a better tool) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `grep -E` or `egrep`, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `,\s*\S+ing`

Matches your first two phrases, doesn't match in your third phrase.

`\s` means 'any whitespace', * means 0 or more of that, `\S` means 'any non-whitespace' (capitalizing the letter is conventional for inverting the character set in regexes - works for `\b` `\s` `\w` `\d`), `+` means 'one or more' and then we match `ing`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't find mention of those regex tokens in `man grep` but now I know what to look for!

Comment: @andryas I use http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html as my regex reference

Comment: Thanks!  That is a useful reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\b` token to match on word boundaries (see [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)).

Something like the following should work:

```
grep -e ".*, \b\w*ing\b"
```

EDIT: Except now I realised that the `\b` is unnecessary, and `.*,\s*\w*ing` would work, as Patashu pointed out.  My regex-fu is rusty.